# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In Connection.php line 664:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Tempor  
  ary failure in name resolution (SQL: select count(`id`) as aggregate from `  
  offers` where (exists (select * from `offers_allegro` where `offers`.`id` =  
   `offers_allegro`.`offer_id` and exists (select * from `allegro_competitor_  
  scan_results` inner join `allegro_offers_to_competitors` on `allegro_compet  
  itor_scan_results`.`id` = `allegro_offers_to_competitors`.`result_id` where  
   `offers_allegro`.`id` = `allegro_offers_to_competitors`.`offer_id`)) or ex  
  ists (select * from `offers_olx` where `offers`.`id` = `offers_olx`.`offer_  
  id` and exists (select * from `olx_competitor_scan_results` inner join `olx  
  _offers_to_competitors` on `olx_competitor_scan_results`.`id` = `olx_offers  
  _to_competitors`.`result_id` where `offers_olx`.`id` = `olx_offers_to_compe  
  titors`.`offer_id`))) and `offers`.`deleted_at` is null)                     
                                                                               

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Tempor  
  ary failure in name resolution                                               
                                                                               

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Tempor  
  ary failure in name resolution                                               
                                                                               

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                                                               
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary  
   failure in name resolution                                                  
                                                                               

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Всем привет, вот такую ошибку выдает при "composer update" Laravel.
вот содержимое .env

```
APP_NAME="LEKKO LOT"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG=daily
APP_LOG_LEVEL=info
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=olx
DB_USERNAME=debian-sys-maint
DB_PASSWORD="pass"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

AWS_KEY=
AWS_SECRET=
AWS_REGION="eu-central-1"
AWS_BUCKET=lekkolot-test

MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@lekkolot.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=LekkoLot

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=



ALLEGRO_DEFAULT_API_ACCOUNT=2
OLX_UA_DEFAULT_API_ACCOUNT=1

#FORM_SHIPMENT_REQUIRED=true
#FORM_PURCHASE_REQUIRED=true
#FORM_CUSTOMS_REQUIRED=true
#FORM_CURRENCY_REQUIRED=true
#FORM_CURRENCY_RATE_REQUIRED=true

ALLEGRO_PL_API_COUNTRY=1
ALLEGRO_PL_API_IS_SANDBOX=false
ALLEGRO_PL_API_CLIENT_ID=
ALLEGRO_PL_API_CLIENT_SECRET=
ALLEGRO_PL_API_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost/auth/allegro/

OTOMOTO_PL_API_COUNTRY=1
OTOMOTO_PL_API_IS_SANDBOX=true
OTOMOTO_PL_API_CLIENT_ID=
OTOMOTO_PL_API_CLIENT_SECRET=
OTOMOTO_PL_API_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost/auth/otomotopl/

OLX_UA_API_DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID=1
OLX_UA_API_CLIENT_ID=
OLX_UA_API_CLIENT_SECRET=
OLX_UA_API_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost/auth/olx/

JWT_SECRET=
JWT_TTL=1
JWT_REFRESH_TTL=7200
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'olx'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'debian-sys-maint'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'PP5GzQ64RM3Lkf1V'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: Вероятно проблема в ваших настройках и миграции при создании [контейнера](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382638/getting-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-temporary-failure-in-name)? Если это так то указывайте полную конфигурацию, которую вы используете чтобы мы не додумывали за вас.

Comment: Очистите кэш в /bootstrap/cache и попробуйте ещё раз. Вообще не понятно что делает Allegro в package:discover в post-autoload-dump сообщении composer.json файла. Смотрите эту библиотеку и этот файл для подсказок.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Очистка кэша не помогла

Comment: в конфиге `DB_HOST=mysql` должно быть `DB_HOST=localhost`, если не существует хост `mysql` (`http://mysql`)

Comment: @Gust Это не поможет, пробывал

Comment: DB_HOST=mysql - подскажите, у вас проект запускается в докере?